# Privacy implications of GCM on MicroG

Tags: privacy, android, google

[GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Cloud_Messaging) (now [FCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebase_Cloud_Messaging) after a change of ownership to a Google subsidiary) is a push notification framework which is commonly used on Android phones. [MicroG](https://microg.org/) is an open source reimplementation of Google proprietary userspace apps and libraries, including GCM, with more focus on openness and privacy.

What kind of information does Google get about me if I am using the MicroG version of GCM in conjunction with messaging apps?

For instance, from [this discussion](https://github.com/vector-im/riot-android/issues/994) about the Matrix protocol:

> The GCM data contains the "cleared" message i.e. sender, room name, message type, text and so on.
>
> If you send an encrypted message, the GCM data don't contain the decrypted message.
>
> If there is no data in the push, it is required to trigger a messages catchup (which is done by default).

from which it seems that it gets quite a lot of metadata over my messages, in addition to presence data (if my phone (identified by a unique ID) is on, which IP it has, and possibly also where it is), which would already be worrying as it is. And I guess that less privacy-oriented messaging apps such as Whatsapp share even more metadata.